# Is this linear map continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, hilbert-spaces, unbounded-operators

Let $A:L^{2}\left( (0,1)\right) \rightarrow L^{2}\left( (0,1)\right) $ be
defined as $Af\left( x\right) =-\ln \left( x\right) f\left( \frac{x}{2}%
\right) $ for every $f\in L^{2}\left( (0,1)\right) $ and $x\in \left(
0,1\right) $

The map $A$ is linear and $\ln \in L^{2}\left( (0,1)\right) $ but I
have no idea if $A$ is bounded or not. That's what I'm trying to answer
to.

Comment: $A$ is not a functional but a linear operator.  The function $\ln x$ is unbounded, therefore the operator is unbounded.

Comment: I can not anderstand since $ln$ is $L^2$

Comment: You get $A1=-\ln x\in L^2,$ but that's not sufficient for boundedness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n\ge 2$ let $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}1 & 0\le x\le {1/n}\\
0 & x>{1/n}
\end{cases}$$
Then $\|f\|_2^2={1\over n}$ and
$$\|Af_n\|_2^2= \int\limits_0^{2/n}\ln^2x \,dx\ge {2\over n}\ln^2(2/n)$$
Thus $${\|Af_n\|_2\over \|f_n\|_2}\ge \sqrt{2}|\ln(2/n)|\underset{n\to \infty}{\longrightarrow}\infty$$

Comment: Thank you so much